# Dynamic array classic asp

Tags: arrays

I'm new in asp.

Do you know why this script has error?

```
<%
    Dim i
    Dim prueba()
    for i=0 to 9
        prueba(i) = i
    next
%>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What error are you seeing when you try to load the page that script is on?

Comment: Classic ASP is a little rusty but do you need the brackets after Dim prueba?

Answer (score 1):

In VBScript you have to use Redim Preserve

```
<%
    Dim i
    Dim prueba()
    Redim preuba(-1)

    For i = 0 to 9
        Redim Preserve preuba(Ubound(preuba)+1)
        preuba(i) = i
    Next

%>
```